# Deploying project-ds file on Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, jboss, seam

Normally I use jboss AS 4.x but I need to deploy on tomcat my project ,but when I mark as deployable my project-ds file an error accours  like 'there  are no server supports single file deployment' ?

seam 2.2.1.final
tomcat 6.0.18
(working version uses jboss 4.2.3 GA)

Answer (score 1):

In Tomcat, you do not declare your datasources using a project-DS.xml file.  Instead, you define them in your Context.xml file, located in your project's META-INF directory.  For more info on that, see this link:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

Answer (score 0):

In JBoss a xyz-ds.xml is transformed into a standard jboss-service.xml (MBean-Descriptor) automaticly. Configure your DS in the context.xml or in the web.xml (depends on the scope of your Datasource).

@see jboss-jca.sar
@see http://labanimal.fudan.edu.cn/docs/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html